# Verification - does $x < \sup A$ necessarily mean $x \in A$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a non-empty and bounded above set $A$, and some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x < \sup A$.

Do we then have that $x \in A$?

Since we assume $\sup A$ exists, it follows that $A \subset \mathbb{R}$.

If we take $x = \sqrt{2}$ and define $A = \{...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2\}$

Then $A$ is non-empty, bounded above and has $\sup A = 2$. Furthermore $x < \sup A$, but $x \notin A$.

I know this seems rather elementary, but I just wanted to make sure there was absolutely no flaw in my example.

Is there an even simpler case for which you could prove this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in your example. In fact you don't need to consider an infinite set as an example. You can just consider any finite set and $x < \min(A) \leq \max(A)$ but $x \notin A$.

Comment: Thanks - this is all I wanted to clear up.

I am getting lots of responses saying I don't need to consider an infinite set, however it is not explicitly stated that $A$ is bounded below, so therefore don't I need to assume $A$ is unbounded below?

Comment: In general $A$ is not bounded below. But to disprove a statement, we just need to provide a counterexample, which you can assume the set is bounded below in specific.

Comment: Oh okay, interesting. That makes sense actually! Thanks

Comment: @piman314 Why would you assume something is unbounded( below) just because it's not explicitly stated to be bounded( below) ?  Not stated just means you don't know if it is go or woe.

Comment: @GrahamKemp This is what I've realised. Assuming the set is unbounded below is about as good as assuming it is bounded below. Neither is explicitly stated!

I am trying to be so rigorous with real-analyis, I honestly love the hell out of this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Just take $x<\inf A$. Then $x$ can't belong to A

Comment: But how can we assume $A$ is bounded below, i.e that $\inf A$ even exists?

Comment: But there is no problem with that, you don't need to assume that A is bounded below to prove that

Answer (score 0):

You could take $A$ to just consist of a single element, e.g., $A=\{1\}$. Then $\sup A=1$. You could take $x$ to be anything less than 1, e.g., take $x=0$.

Comment: But the question says $A$ is non-empty and bounded above. It doesn't mention that $A$ is bounded below.

in any case, does my example still work?

Comment: @piman314 $A$ is not empty, contains $1$, and it is bounded above, by $2$ for example.

Comment: Your example also works, yes.  Just because it did not say that $A$ was bounded below does not mean that we must choose $A$ to not be bounded below.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but if we take $A = \{1\}$ then it is also bounded below, which is an unfair assumption, no?

Comment: Your conditions says: "a non-empty and bounded above set". You have not restrictions on being bounded below.

Comment: Got it - all we needed was a counter example. Thanks everyone!